# How to broadcast sum of list of list?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

How to broadcast the sum of list of list in an efficient way?
below is a working code, but its not quite efficient when list1 has nth value like 30 elements.
Any improvement on this?
from numpy import sum
import numpy as np

```
list1 = [[4,8],[8,16]]
list2 = [2] 
elemSum=[sum(list1[0]),sum(list1[1])]
print((np.array(elemSum)/np.array(list2)))
```

prints:

```
[ 6. 12.] # expected output
```

I want a single line like this below , eliminating the declaration of variable elemSum, but it yields incorrect output since it sums 2 elements to 1

```
print(sum(np.array(list1)/np.array(list2)))
```

prints:

```
18.0 # not expected it sums 2 elements to 1
```

Comment: Are you working with `numpy` or with regular `list` objects?

Comment: I'm working with numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.sum` takes an optional `axis` argument, which can be used for partial sums along a single axis:

```
>>> list1 = np.array([[4,8],[8,16]])
>>> list2 = np.array([2])
>>> np.sum(list1)
36
>>> np.sum(list1, axis=1)
array([12, 24])
>>> np.sum(list1, axis=1) / list2
array([ 6., 12.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `numpy` the entire time, don't mess with lists if you want arrays:

```
list1 = [[4,8],[8,16]]
list2 = [2]
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array(list1)
arr2 = np.array(list2)
```

Then simply:

```
result = arr1.sum(axis=1) / arr2
```